# Strange CPU utilisation for Node.js when run as cron job

Tags: mysql, node.js, cron

I have a node.js script that executes about 1200 SQL queries to a MySQL DB.

**When the script is run from the command line:**

- It takes about 45 mins to complete.
- `top` reports:

  - CPU utilisation for `mysqld` close to 100%.
  - CPU utilisation for `node` less than 1%.
- This makes sense because of the load on `mysqld`.

**When the script is executed from cron:**

- It takes about 93 mins to complete.
- `top` reports:

  - CPU utilisation for `mysqld` ~= 50%.
  - CPU utilisation for `node` ~= 50%.

Why is there a difference in CPU utilisation when the script is run from different environments?

How can I debug the script when it's run from cron?

**What I've tried (with no success):**

- In `crontab` I've tried starting the node script from a shell script and also directly.
- Removing all `console.log` and `fs` calls in case they affected the cron environment.

Comment: Your statement isn't clear. It's nearly 100 for MySQL and about 1 for node. Then from cron, both use about the same. But, you say mysql uses more and node uses less. How does the total amount of time taken to perform the operations differ? Is everything run from an **identical** state when you run the comparisons?

Comment: Without more detail added to your question, troubleshooting this is pure speculation.

Comment: I've reworded the question to hopefully clarify. What other details can I provide?

Comment: Is it running as the same account? Are you resetting the environment back to a consistent state after each trial? Can you add timing information to each query and compare them side by side?

Comment: Yes, it's running as the same account (ie, `crontab -e` was run from the same user account). I can add timing info to the script and `tail` it when it's running from `cron`. Which environment do you mean I should be resetting? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're testing under the exact same conditions when you run both tests.

Comment: @WiredPrairie The same conditions exist for both tests. The only difference is that one is run in the TTY context and the other from cron. In the TTY context the script completes after 45 mins. In the cron context the script completes after 93 mins.